# R shiny plot: window resize forces reevaluation

Tags: r, user-interface, click, shiny

I am having some trouble with some dependencies in my shiny app.
My situation is: I have a clickable plot. Upon a click, a table below the plot shows the closest point in the plot.

The problem is that, depending on window sizing, this new row of information can trigger a scrollbar to appear on the right of the browser window. This changes the window size available to shiny, and shiny re-draws the plot. On redrawing, the click event is lost, the table is updated, and the table is now empty again. This means the scroll bar is removed, and the plot is re-drawn again, with an empty table below.

I don't mind the re-draw (once) to accommodate for the scroll bar (which in turn accommodates the new row in the table). But I do not want to loose the click event data!

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

UI <- fluidPage(mainPanel(
  plotOutput("plot", click = "plot_click"),
  tableOutput("info_click")
))

SERVER <- function(input, output) {
# make simple plot
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_point()
})
# read local point from click
output$info_click <- renderTable({
     nearPoints(mtcars, input$plot_click, threshold = 10, maxpoints = 1)
})
}

runApp(shinyApp(UI,SERVER))
```

In order to trigger the annoying event, size the window so that the height and width matches *without scrollbars*. When you click, scrollbars should be generated, which re-draws the plot, etc, etc and you lose the click data.

I have tried various combinations of `isolate({})` and `observeEvent({})` but I have now given up!

I took a screen capture video of my predicament, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsM1WppTQi8

(Chrome on Windows 10 ... same applies to Firefox and Opera.)

Note that my screen capture program seems to have replaced my mouse pointer with a white cross slightly shifted from the true location. Please ignore that - I am actually clicking on the black points.

You see that when I click a point, the table below is populated. When this happens, the scrollbar on the right appears, the plot re-draws, the "click" is forgotten, the table becomes empty, the scrollbar disappears, and the plot is re-drawn again.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in safari. I made your example simpler at https://gist.github.com/hadley/cb45743defef1fb221a9

Comment: @hadley Thanks for the simplification. I pared my actual use-case down a lot, but yours is neater for sure. I've changed my code to match your suggestion (much simplified UI part). Also, added a video.

Comment: I'd recommend filing an issue on shiny's GitHub

Comment: Issue registered here:
https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/937

Comment: I have a very similar problem, OP and @hadley's versions are both "fixed" by adding `tags$style(type="text/css", "body { overflow-y: scroll; }")` to the `fluidPage`. It is a hack solution as far as I'm concerned, because the "click data" will not survive a resize of the application window.